# C starting a X11 session using system() vs using execl()

Tags: c, unix, fork

I have created a daemon-like program that will start a X11 session for a specific user under its own enviroment, after he authenticates himself.

The first approach was to use a command using `system()`, where I would impersonate the user and start the x11 session as follows:

```
std::string cmd = "echo daemonuserpwd | sudo -S su " + unixUser + " -c 'xinit -- :4' &";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

This works flawless, and calls the `.xinitrc` file located in the user's home directory, which is a necessary step as I use it to start up the required programs which I need for the purpose the application Im working in.

However, I read about the problems with `system()`, so I tried to go bit further and use fork to create the user enviroment, and start the session using `execl()`, as follows:

```
int child = fork();
if(child == 0)
{
    struct passwd * userInfo = getpwnam(unixUser.c_str());
    setgid(userInfo->pw_gid);
    setuid(userInfo->pw_uid);
    system("whoami");
    execl("/usr/bin/xinit", "xinit", "--", ":4", (char*)0);
    //system("xinit -- :4");
}
```

This also works, the debugging command `system("whoami");` says im the right user. The X11 session is started, however, the `.xinitrc` file is not called when the session is started from the fork process. I also tried to execute the command with system, after setting up the user enviroment, with same result (Both options call the default `xinitrc` in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.

Am I missing something in order the `.xinitrc` file to be called as well when using the `fork()` approach?

Disclaimer:
User authentication is performed with libpam, and the user input is sanitetized properly to prevent injections.

---

EDIT: The final workaround using `execle` as suggested by @LieRyan:

```
struct passwd * userInfo = getpwnam(unixUser.c_str());
char buf[0xff];
sprintf(buf, "HOME=%s", userInfo->pw_dir);
char *env[] = {buf, NULL};
execle("/usr/bin/sudo", "sudo", "-u", unixUser.c_str(), "xinit", "--", ":4", (char*)0, env);
```

Comment: Another thing you may want to consider, to use setuid/setgid, your program had to run as root. Consider, if this is an unnecessary risk. You may want to consider running `execl("/usr/bin/sudo", "-u", unixUser, "xinit", "--", ":4", (char*)0)` and have your daemon user be whitelisted in /etc/sudoers to NOPASSWD when running xinit.

Comment: @LieRyan Thank you very much! I followed both of your advices (and also found a workaround to use `pam_authenticate()` without root privileges), and Im able to run the daemon without root privs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setuid` changes who the process belongs to, but it doesn't alter the environment variables that would be set if that user had logged in so `$HOME` won't be pointing at the right place to pick up the ".xinitrc" file.

The following line of code should fix that for you.

```
setenv("HOME",userInfo->pw_dir,1);
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much

Comment: Note that setenv changes the environment variable of the current process as well, which may have unintended side effects, if this is undesirable, you may want to use `execle` instead.

Comment: True, @LieRyan, but not much relevant when you've `fork()`ed, and / or if you're assuming (unsafely) that `execl()` will not fail, as the OP appears to do, or if you ensure that the process terminates in the event that `execl()` does fail.

Comment: @JohnBollinger if you are referring to check the returned value by `execl()`, I left it out for the sake of simplicity.